# How can I check which radio button is selected and apply an appropriate behaviour with if else statements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Here is my **codepen**:

http://codepen.io/ekilja01/full/KaMXjp/

I'm trying do detect which radio button is selected and then display appropriate output whether Celsius or Fahrenheit  as the final output.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <i class="fa fa-thermometer-empty fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <br><br><br>
     
      <form>
        <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="f" id="fahrenheit"> Fahrenheit &deg;F;<br>
           <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="c" id ="celsius" > Celsius &deg;C<br>
      </form>
         <div class="yourlocation">
           <h1>Your location is: </h1>
             <p class="yourLocationGoesHere">
             </p>
         </div>

       <h1>Your current weather is: </h1>

         <div class="showTemperature">
            <p class="showDegree"></p>
         </div>

         <div class="icon">
         </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data){

  var len = data.length;
  var location = "";
  var temperature = "";
  var celsius = Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.floor(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);


  function checkSelection(){   if(document.getElementById('celsius').checked) {
  //Celsius radio button is checked
  return celsius;
   }else if(document.getElementById('fahrenheit').checked) {
     //Fahrenheit radio button is checked
     return fahrenheit;
   } else {
      return "Please select Fahrenheit or Celsius"
   }
                         };


   location += "<p>'" + data.name + ", " + data.sys.country + "'</p>";

   temperature += "<p>'" + checkSelection() + "'</p>";
   $(".yourLocationGoesHere").html(location);

   $(".showDegree").html(temperature);


    });
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the specific problem and question? you mentioned a goal, but not what the code is doing differently than expected

Comment: When I switch between Fahrenheit or Celsius it doesn't show under YOUR CURRENT WHEATER IS: I mean it has to detect in what format user would like to get a final output and display it. If statement doesn't do this. If you try to select either Fahrenheit or Celsius it doesn't do the switch.

Comment: You need a change event listener for that http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @charlietfl is right. The code you wrote is only executed once, after the page has successfully loaded. You need a piece a code that's run everytime your input changes. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: `$(':radio').change(function(){ if (this.id === 'celcius'){....}else{...}})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to listen to change event of radios and do whatever it is you want within conditional of the event handler

```
$(':radio').change(function(){ 
   // "this" will be the checked radio element       
   if (this.id === 'celsius'){
     // code you want for celsius
   }else{
     // code you want for fahrenheit
   }
});
```

Comment: $(':radio').change(function(){ 
          
      if (this.id === 'celsius'){
    
     temperature += "<p>'" + celsius+ "'</p>";  
        $(".showDegree").html(temperature);
      }else{
     
     temperature += "<p>'" + fahrenheit+ "'</p>";  
        $(".showDegree").html(temperature);
       }
     });
But after this i'm getting and output in column each time I switch between Celsius or Fahrenheit. Please have a look. http://codepen.io/ekilja01/full/KaMXjp/

Comment: no need for `temperature +=` , just set something like `$(".showDegree").html( "<p>" + celsius+ "</p>"); `

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `attach` a `change` event handler when your radio buttons are changed.

Further more, you have to declare `celsius` and `fahrenheit` variables outside in order to access them in `change` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var celsius="";
  var fahrenheit="";
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data){   
     var len = data.length;
     var location = "";
     celsius = Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15);
     fahrenheit = Math.floor(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);
   location += "<p>'" + data.name + ", " + data.sys.country + "'</p>";
    $(".yourLocationGoesHere").html(location);        
  });
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  temperature = "";
  if(document.getElementById('celsius').checked) {
        temperature += "<p>'" + celsius+ "'</p>";  
        $(".showDegree").html(temperature);
         
    }else if(document.getElementById('fahrenheit').checked) {
      temperature += "<p>'" + fahrenheit+ "'</p>";  
        $(".showDegree").html(temperature);
    } else {
      return "Please select Fahrenheit or Celsius"
    }
});
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P');

body {
  max-width: 42em;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 5px auto;
  color: #161616;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center !important;
}

i {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/43f8201759.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <i class="fa fa-thermometer-empty fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<br><br><br>
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="f" id="fahrenheit"> Fahrenheit &deg;F;<br>
  <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="c" id ="celsius"> Celsius &deg;C<br>
</form>
<div class="yourlocation">
  <h1>Your location is: </h1>
  <p class="yourLocationGoesHere">
  </p>
</div>

<h1>Your current weather is: </h1>

<div class="showTemperature">
  <p class="showDegree"></p>
</div>
    
    <div class="icon">
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: no need to use global window variables. Agree they need to be properly scoped but better to scope them inside the ready function , or an IIFE, and not as globals to avoid polluting window and prevent collisions

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data){

  var len = data.length;
  var location = "";
  var temperature = "";
  var celsius = Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.floor(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);


  function checkSelection(){   if(document.getElementById('celsius').checked) {
  //Celsius radio button is checked
  return celsius;
   }else if(document.getElementById('fahrenheit').checked) {
     //Fahrenheit radio button is checked
     return fahrenheit;
   } else {
      return "Please select Fahrenheit or Celsius"
   }
                         };

    
function update(){
   

   var loc = "<p>'" + data.name + ", " + data.sys.country + "'</p>";
   temperature += "<p>'" + checkSelection() + "'</p>";
   $(".yourLocationGoesHere").html(loc);

   $(".showDegree").html(temperature);
}
    
    update();
    
    $('input[type=radio][name="celsiusOrFahrenheit"]').on('change', update);

    
   
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <i class="fa fa-thermometer-empty fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

      <form>
        <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="f" id="fahrenheit"> Fahrenheit &deg;F;<br>
        <input type="radio" name="celsiusOrFahrenheit" value="c" id ="celsius" > Celsius &deg;C<br>
      </form>
         <div class="yourlocation">
           <h1>Your location is: </h1>
             <p class="yourLocationGoesHere">
             </p>
         </div>

       <h1>Your current weather is: </h1>

         <div class="showTemperature">
            <p class="showDegree"></p>
         </div>

         <div class="icon">
         </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

add == true and you are ready

document.getElementById('celsius').checked==true

Comment: `checked` returns boolean...this does nothing different